# Nesting Components on laravel 10x with livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I'm working with laravel 10 and livewire, everything was going well display the table data, data order, create new data but when about to edit this data, I wanted to do the same as I did for the creation of new records, basically use a modal with livewire to edit.
I get this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'categoryName')
It only opens a modal for the first record but it does not show the data in the input and the other modals never open, not even the button to close the modal is enabled
I am new learning to use Laravel and working with livewire caught my attention so if you know of any solution I would greatly appreciate it.
Greetings
[[backend code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Ql2.png)]
[[frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uyMk.png)]